# MySQL query with unexpected plus sign

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am using a tool to scan for potential SQL-injection vulnerabilities in my application. I ran across a test where it sends the following in a form field:

```
+ (SELECT 0 FROM (SELECT SLEEP(10))qsqli_1111)
```

This results in a query like the following (against a MySQL database):

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeField IN (+ (SELECT 0 FROM (SELECT SLEEP(10))qsqli_1111))
```

The tool (correctly) infers that there is probably a SQL injection vulnerability because the query takes 10 seconds longer than when sending a simple value. (i.e. the `SLEEP(10)` is executing.)

My question is: **what does this syntax actually do**? What is the plus sign doing? What is the `qsqli_1111`? Why is there a `SELECT 0 FROM`?

I've tried googling "mysql syntax plus sign" and "qsqli_1111" but I'm not finding anything. I don't know what to look for in MySQL manual or elsewhere...

Comment: I don't know about the plus sign but for the rest: `qsqli_1111` is a subquery alias because it is mandatory on the syntax and `select 0` is just an workaround to select something from that subquery in this case the `sleep(10)` function to run. The name `qsqli_1111` is probably from the tool you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` is a unary operator that does almost nothing.  Well, I think it will convert any value to a number.  It is analogous to `-`, but without changing the sign.

In this case, it is doing something to the result of the subquery.  Of course the result is already a number.  It might be there to fool the optimizer, so the subquery doesn't get optimized away.  That is speculation.

The `qsqli_1111` is easier to explain.  It is a table alias and it is needed to prevent a syntax error.

Comment: select +'02bc' -- >'02bc'. The minus does indeed convert to a number, but the + seems to do nothing. Am I missing some switch/sql mode here?

Comment: Funnily enough, you can use '--' to convert to a number without changing the sign. Beware of extra spaces after the double minus though. Example: select --'01A' -- >1

Answer (score 1):

the plus is concatenation. its so they can run extra sql in your statement. They will also use or. The select 0 is just that it return 0. and the last part is an alias I believe. You should be preparing your sql before executing it. Never allow straight sql run against your server

Comment: Concatenation or addition. The plus will make sure that the subquery would not cause a syntax error regardless the type of data within the in operator.

Comment: in Mysql, '+' is only addition, not concatenation